# Getting the signature of a FunctionDecl

Tags: clang, llvm, libclang, libtooling

I got the FunctionDecl for the definition of a function. There is no declaration for this function.

For example:

```
int foo(char c, double d)
{
   ...
}
```

How do I get the signature (qualifier, return type, function name, parametrs) as a valid signature I could use to make a declaration?

Comment: See my example in below!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430971/how-to-get-function-definition-signature-as-a-string-in-clang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the easiest way is to use the lexer to get the signature of the function. Since I wanted to make a declaration out of a definition, I wanted the declaration to look exactly like the definition. 
Therefore I defined a `SourceRange` from the start of the function to the beginning of the body of the function (minus the opening "{") and let the lexer give me this range as a string.

```
static std::string getDeclaration(const clang::FunctionDecl* D)
{
  clang::ASTContext& ctx = D->getASTContext();
  clang::SourceManager& mgr = ctx.getSourceManager();

  clang::SourceRange range = clang::SourceRange(D->getSourceRange().getBegin(), D->getBody()->getSourceRange().getBegin());
  StringRef s = clang::Lexer::getSourceText(clang::CharSourceRange::getTokenRange(range), mgr, ctx.getLangOpts());

  return s.substr(0, s.size() - 2).str().append(";");
}
```

This solution assums that the `FunctionDecl` is a definition (has a body).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Unfortunately I have found it produces incorrect results when there are ctor initializers - they are included in the result, though they are not a part of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you were looking for...

```
bool VisitDecl(Decl* D) {
  auto k = D->getDeclKindName();
  auto r = D->getSourceRange();
  auto b = r.getBegin();
  auto e = r.getEnd();
  auto& srcMgr = Context->getSourceManager();
  if (srcMgr.isInMainFile(b)) {
    auto d = depth - 2u;
    auto fname = srcMgr.getFilename(b);
    auto bOff = srcMgr.getFileOffset(b);
    auto eOff = srcMgr.getFileOffset(e);
    llvm::outs() << std::string(2*d,' ') << k << "Decl ";
    llvm::outs() << "<" << fname << ", " << bOff << ", " << eOff << "> ";
    if (D->getKind() == Decl::Kind::Function) {
      auto fnDecl = reinterpret_cast<FunctionDecl*>(D);
      llvm::outs() << fnDecl->getNameAsString() << " ";
      llvm::outs() << "'" << fnDecl->getType().getAsString() << "' ";
    } else if (D->getKind() == Decl::Kind::ParmVar) {
      auto pvDecl = reinterpret_cast<ParmVarDecl*>(D);
      llvm::outs() << pvDecl->getNameAsString() << " ";
      llvm::outs() << "'" << pvDecl->getType().getAsString() << "' ";
    }
    llvm::outs() << "\n";
  }
  return true;
}
```

Sample output:

```
FunctionDecl <foo.c, 48, 94> foo 'int (unsigned int)' 
  ParmVarDecl <foo.c, 56, 69> x 'unsigned int' 
  CompoundStmt <foo.c, 72, 94> 
    ReturnStmt <foo.c, 76, 91> 
      ParenExpr <foo.c, 83, 91> 
        BinaryOperator <foo.c, 84, 17> 
          ImplicitCastExpr <foo.c, 84, 84> 
            DeclRefExpr <foo.c, 84, 84> 
          ParenExpr <foo.c, 28, 45> 
            BinaryOperator <foo.c, 29, 43> 
              ParenExpr <foo.c, 29, 39> 
                BinaryOperator <foo.c, 30, 12> 
                  IntegerLiteral <foo.c, 30, 30> 
                  IntegerLiteral <foo.c, 12, 12> 
              IntegerLiteral <foo.c, 43, 43>
```

You will notice the `reinterpret_cast<OtherDecl*>(D)` function calls. `Decl` is the base class for all AST `OtherDecl` classes like `FunctionDecl` or `ParmVarDecl`. So reinterpreting the pointer is allowed and gets you access to that particular AST node's attributes. Since these more-specific AST Nodes inherit the `NamedDecl` and `ValueDecl` classes, obtaining the function name and the function type (signature) is simple. The same can be applied to the base class `Stmt` and other inherited classes like the `OtherExpr` classes.