# libclang skips function return type for C

Tags: c++, c, libclang

I have been trying to parse C headers using libclang's c++ API. I am able to parse functions, however, clang skips their return types.

Here is simplified version of what my code looks like;

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <clang-c/Index.h>

CXCursor prevCursor;
CXTranslationUnit unit;

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex( 0, 0 );
    unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
        index, "example.h", nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0,
        CXTranslationUnit_SkipFunctionBodies
        );

    if ( unit == nullptr )
    {
        cerr << "Unable to parse translation unit. Quitting." << endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor( unit );
    prevCursor = cursor;
    clang_visitChildren(
        cursor,
        []( CXCursor c, CXCursor parent, CXClientData clientData )
        {
            CXSourceLocation loc = clang_getCursorLocation( c );

            if ( !clang_Location_isFromMainFile( loc ) )
                return CXChildVisit_Continue;

            // CXType t;
            // CXType result;
            switch ( clang_getCursorKind( c ) )
            {
                case CXCursor_FunctionDecl:
                    // t = clang_getCursorType( c );
                    // result = clang_getResultType( t );
                    cout << "function name: "
                         << (char*) clang_getCursorDisplayName( c ).data << " "
                         << "previous: "
                         << (char*) clang_getCursorDisplayName( prevCursor ).data
                         << endl;
                    // cout << (char*) clang_getTypeSpelling( result ).data << " "
                         // << (char*) clang_getCursorSpelling( c ).data
                         // << endl;

                    prevCursor = c;
                    break;
                default:
                    prevCursor = c;
                    break;
            }

            return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
        },
        nullptr );

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit( unit );
    clang_disposeIndex( index );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

example.h file:

```
#define MY_TYPE void

struct s0
{
    int a;
};

MY_TYPE func0();

char func1( int x );

long func2( int y );
```

```
And the output:
function name: func0() previous: a
function name: func1(int) previous: func0()
function name: func2(int) previous: x
```

It seems libclang doesn't treat function return type the same way as function parameters and just ignores it.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Uncommenting the code according to Hasturkun's suggestions I was able to get function return type:

```
function name: func0() previous: a
void func0
function name: func1(int) previous: func0()
char func1
function name: func2(int) previous: x
long func2
```

I was trying to get the source location where the function declaration begins. I can kind of hack around this, but I thought there can be a better solution.

Comment: @Community - In case the _person_ reviewing this flag needs a reason, the statement _"It seems libclang doesn't treat function return type the same way as function parameters and just ignores it."_ is clear enough to be actionable by most humans, if not by a bot.

Comment: Added C++ tag, and kept C.  Both are being discussed in question in this case.

Comment: Actual example input and output and desired output would be helpful, but I think there is enough description of the output for it to be a clear question.

Comment: Please note that the function you are calling describes its result as "The display name contains extra information that helps identify the cursor".  C++ doesn't overload on return type, so return type doesn't help identify the entity.  Apparently it isn't trying to spit out a valid declaration, just enough information to disambiguate (like you might need for an error message)

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888594/ignoring-return-values-in-c) where user purposefully wants to ignore return types.   May be useful for contrasting against what you are doing.

Comment: I haven't used libclang, so just peeking through the documentation, but I'm guessing you want to get the type by `clang_getCursorType`, and then use `clang_getResultType` over that. Also, [this seems relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867090).

Comment: Re: Source location, you can apparently map from a cursor to a file/line/column using `clang_getCursorLocation` and `clang_getExpansionLocation` (or possibly `clang_getPresumedLocation`)  See [Physical source locations](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__LOCATIONS.html) in the libclang documentation.